# FilteredQueryBuilder deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between FilteredQueryBuilder and QueryFilterBuilder as both were deprecated since 2.0 and alternative java code for FilteredQueryBuilder

```
 FilteredQueryBuilder filteredQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(termsQueryBuilder, null); 
 QueryFilterBuilder queryFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.queryFilter(esQueryBuilder);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since queries and filters have now been merged, those constructs make no sense anymore.

`FilteredQueryBuilder` was used to create a [`filtered` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-filtered-query.html), i.e. a scored query constrained by a set of filters. Instead of using a `FilteredQueryBuilder`, you should now use

- a `bool/filter` created using `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(...)`
- or a `bool/must_not` created using `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(...)` if you need to negate your filter

`QueryFilterBuilder` was used to create a [`query` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-query-filter.html), i.e. a non-scored query inside a filtered context. Instead of using a `QueryFilterBuilder`, you should now

- use a `bool/must` query created using `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(...)` if you need to AND your queries
- or use a `bool/should` created using  `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(...)` if you need to OR your queries

Comment: FilteredQueryBuilder filteredQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(catQuery, catalogEnabledFilter);           
        Alternative for this --> BoolQueryBuilder filteredQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(catQuery).filter(catalogEnabledFilter); Is this correct

Answer (score 0):

According to [Compound queries -> Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-bool-query) you should implement filters al *bool* queries.

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery()
    .must(termQuery("content", "test1"))    
    .must(termQuery("content", "test4"))    
    .mustNot(termQuery("content", "test2")) 
    .should(termQuery("content", "test3"))  
    .filter(termQuery("content", "test5"));
```